# Strange date behavior with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document in my database that gets displayed like this when inspected with MongoDB Compass:

[image: mongodb object]

Now I have experimented a bit with it on the command line:

[image: command line experiments]

I understand that `getMonth` returns one because they range from 0 to 11, but why does `getDay` return numbers that to me appear have no relation whatsoever with the saved date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look documentation for [getDay()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) you will find out that:

> The getDay() method returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) for the
>   specified date.

I think that on your computer culture week starts on Sunday. So you are getting numbers that you are gettings.

Also I bolive that you wanted to use [getDate()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp) method:

> The getDate() method returns the day of the month (from 1 to 31) for
>   the specified date.

Answer (score 2):

getDay() returns the day of the week (from 0-6).

So wednesday will be 2.

Try getDate() to return the day of the month.